# Memcached-How to check if the query result has been changed

Tags: php, memcached

Is there any feature in Memcached to figure out whether there is any changes in the query result of my Database and if there is any changes to the result, use that one, otherwise use the Memcaches, which already stored the previous result of the query? I guess this feature was available in ASP.NET, but I'm not sure in PHP.

Thanks

Comment: It's called "cache invalidation". And it's **hard**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is "no there isn't".

Analyzing the queries for updates would completely defeat the point in using Memcached in the first place. You will need to invalidate the cache record during any database updates so that it will regenerate on the next call with the correct data.